# WSDL Complex Type repeating property in VB.net

Tags: arrays, vb.net, service, properties, wsdl

Apologies for my terminology and I hope I am giving enough information here. I am working in VB.net and have loaded a connected service URL which pulled in a wsdl file. One of the complex type objects I need to populate in code defined in the wsdl is named **deliveryaddressType**, is non repeating, and has 5 properties I can set. Four of the properties are simple and expect a single string value. One of them also expects a string value but the element *can* repeat up to two times. This is what I currently have:

```
Dim DeliveryAddress As New deliveryaddressType

     DeliveryAddress.addressline(0) = "address line 1"
     DeliveryAddress.city = "city"
     DeliveryAddress.zip = "zip"
     DeliveryAddress.state = "state"
     DeliveryAddress.country = "USA"
```

Because addressline can potentially have 2 values, it will not simply just let me set DeliveryAddress.addressline = "address line 1".

I believe its expecting an array of addressline properties potentially? So I tried setting addressline(0) in which I get an "object reference not set to instance of an object".

deliveryAddressType itself should not be an array, but the property itself should be? Do I need to somehow instantiate the addressline property as an array with a specified length of 1 so that I can set (0)? Am I thinking about this the right way or am I totally off?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I believe I figured this out with the following line of code before setting the addressline(0) property. **DeliveryAddress.addressline = New String(1) {}**

```
Dim DeliveryAddress As New deliveryaddressType
DeliveryAddress.addressline = New String(1) {}

 DeliveryAddress.addressline(0) = "address line 1"
 DeliveryAddress.city = "city"
 DeliveryAddress.zip = "zip"
 DeliveryAddress.state = "state"
 DeliveryAddress.country = "USA"
```